# How to rename files downloaded with wget -r

Tags: wget

I want to download an entire website using the wget -r command and change the name of the file.
I have tried with:

`wget -r -o doc.txt "http....`

hoping that the OS would have automatically create file in order like doc1.txt doc2.txt but It actually save the stream of the stdout in that file.
Is there any way to do this with just one command?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option to create incremental filenames automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-r` tells wget to recursively get resources from a host.

`-o file` saves log messages to file instead of the standard error. I think that is not what you are looking for, I think it is `-O file`.

`-O file` stores the resource(s) in the given file, instead of creating a file in the current directory with the name of the resource. If used in conjunction with `-r`, it causes wget to store all resources concatenated to that file.

Since `wget -r` downloads and stores more than one file, recreating the server file tree in the local system, it has no sense to indicate the name of *one* file to store.

If what you want is to rename all downloaded files to match the pattern `docX.txt`, you can do it with a different command after `wget` has end:

```
wget -r http....

i=1
while read file
do
    mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/doc$i.txt"
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done < <(find . -type f)
```

Comment: ok perfect, since the wget command is a subroutine of a python program I will just change the name of the files after dowload.